# Onclick and jQuery click working together but return false not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick and jQuery click working together but return false not working in jquery. I want to validate fields before on onclick open next page. Problem with my code is that if filed are blank in that case it open next page. I use return false in each empty case. So until all fields are not filled up. next page should not open.

**Html Code**

```
<button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button secondary" onclick="$('login:guest').checked=true; checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php //echo $this->__('Checkout as Guest') ?></span></span></button>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
   jQuery('#onepage-guest-register-button').click(function(e){
   var email=jQuery('#login-email').val();
   jQuery('.validate-email').attr('value', email);
   var login_name = jQuery('#login_name').val();
   var login_phone = jQuery('#login_phone').val();
   var login_email = jQuery('#login_email').val();
   alert("name"+login_name+'phone'+login_phone+'email'+login_email);
   if(login_name==''){ jQuery('.login_name').text('Please enter full name'); return false; }else{ jQuery('.login_name').empty();}
   if(login_phone==''){ jQuery('.login_phone').text('Please enter Phone Number');return false;}else{ jQuery('.login_phone').empty();}
   if(login_email==''){ jQuery('.login_email').text('Please enter Phone email');return false;}else{ jQuery('.login_email').empty();}
   //alert('trigger');
   jQuery('#onepage-guest-register-button').trigger('onclick');
 });
```

Comment: Why do you have both an inline binding and a non-inline binding on the same element?

Comment: Also `$('login:guest').checked=true` is not valid.  jQuery does not directly expose dom properties.  The correct format is `$('login:guest').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: What you mean ? button onclick="$('login:guest').checked=true; checkout.setMethod();". Its not right ?

Comment: Yes, that is syntactically incorrect as I noted.

Comment: jQuery('#onepage-guest-register-button').trigger("onclick","$('login:guest').prop('checked', true)");

Comment: You should give the onclick a function, not a string.

Comment: I replace button onclick with your code

Comment: jQuery('#onepage-guest-register-button').trigger(onclick());

Comment: You should give the onclick a function, not a string. You mean in js trigger function?

Comment: `jQuery('#onepage-guest-register-button').click(function(e){`  You already have an example in your OP of how to give a function to the click binding.

Comment: Can you right the code in your answer?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you at this point.  All I have done is advise you to consolidate your logic in the click binding and fix that one syntax error.  This may not fix whatever issue you were seeing, but it is an issue.

Comment: I edited my question. Please check if I am right or not as per you suggested.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct syntax for changing the property.  But again, I would put those two things in your click handler, rather than having an inline binding, so all your logic is in one place and you know for certain what things are happening in what order.

Comment: Yes. I understand, now I remove onclick for html button and Jquery('login:guest').prop('checked', true); but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `onclick` attribute with `onclick` event handler. It's just plain silly.

In most cases, it's better to go with the latter.

1) Remove `onclick` attribute

```
<button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button secondary"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

2) Move the logic into your `onclick` event handler.

```
jQuery('#onepage-guest-register-button').click(function(e){
    // no idea
    var email = jQuery('#login-email').val();
    jQuery('.validate-email').attr('value', email);

    // get values
    var login_name = jQuery('#login_name').val();
    var login_phone = jQuery('#login_phone').val();
    var login_email = jQuery('#login_email').val();

    // flag if errors is found; assume no errors by default
    var err = false;

    // clear errors?
    jQuery('.login_name').empty();
    jQuery('.login_phone').empty();
    jQuery('.login_email').empty();

    // show errors if any
    if (login_name == '') { 
        jQuery('.login_name').text('Please enter full name');
        err = true;
    }
    if (login_phone == ''){ 
        jQuery('.login_phone').text('Please enter Phone Number');
        err = true;
    }
    if (login_email == ''){ 
        jQuery('.login_email').text('Please enter Phone email');
        err = true;
    }

    // do the appropriate action depending if there are errors or not
    if (err) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $('login:guest').prop('checked', true); 
        checkout.setMethod();
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (opcheckoutlogin.js:53)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)

Comment: Can you please check my question again. I edited my question (Button onclick method in html).